# Large data of Equity Price download from Eikon thomson reuters datastream

Tags: equities, data, price

I like to download all Chinese ( more than 4000 stocks) stocks daily price data from 1990 to 2020 from Eikon Thomson Reuters datastream. However, I failed to select and download all stocks together. For example, if I download data for a particular sector ( maybe 200-300 stocks), then that it is working. But can not select all 4000 stocks together. Is there any way by which I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me is choosing each sector for a specific country manually, through the Excel add-in of Eikon (Datasteam -> Series requests -> Time series request). A window  pops-up, that asks for the *Series/list* and what *datatype* you want. You click the orange box *find series*.  Then you have to find through the search bar each sector in China. For each entry, there is a blank box that you can tick. Once you have selected all sectors, you load them by clicking the *use* button.  The excel returns to the time-series navigator (the first window that appeared) and ask what datatype you need. You enter the word **MNEM**, which refers to the mnemonic code (unique for each stock). By clicking *submit*, you get the unique identity code for each stock.

The excel downloads essentially the mnemonic code for every chinese stock. You can copy the mnemonic codes in a different spreadsheet. From this spreadsheet, you can create a custom list from cell range  (Datasteam -> Utilities -> Create list (From range)). The custom list can be used anytime to retrieve the stock price (**P**) or other measures of interest, without repeating the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing for S&P500. Downloaded the list of stocks into an excel with RIC codes. in excel use function =concat(transpose(RIC column range)&",") to merge rows and separate by comma so that you can copy a single row into Excel-->Datastream and simply tick the RIC box on Time Series Request. My range B24 to B110 corresponds to the RIC column for the SP500 Tech sector.
[image]

[image]